# Custom Russian Phonetic Keyboard

Tags: keyboard-layout, gedit

I tried to custom Russian phonetic keyboard through Terminal. To do this I wrote: cd /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/
then: sudo gedit ru
The document " ru (/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols) - gedit " appeared on the desktop. I changed all the keys that suited me, saved the file and restarted the computer. However, the changes didn't work out. I checked the document again. The changes are there, but the keys still code for the old layout. I think I am missing some important point. Please help.

By the way I get in Terminal this message:

** (gedit:14887): WARNING **: Could not load Gedit repository: Typelib file for namespace 'GtkSource', version '3.0' not found

(gedit:14887): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/roma/.config/ibus/bus is not root!

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

> ** (gedit:14887): WARNING **: Could not load Gedit repository: Typelib file for namespace 'GtkSource', version '3.0' not found

```
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-gtksource-3.0
```

will fix this warning.

Inspired by:
[gedit: should depend on gir1.2-gtksource-3.0](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=627978)